# Excel VBA Clear indirect dropdown cell within a column range

Tags: excel, vba

I have successfully used the code below to clear the contents of an indirect cell based on a change of a dropdown list in order to prevent mismatched data.

For example my first drop down cell is D2 and has 3 options, when an option is selected, my second cell F2 (based on named ranges) changes to show the choices specific to the selected option.
When a user changes the first option in D2, the code triggers and clears out the contents of F2 so a new selection can be made preventing mis-matched data.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    'Clear Adjustment Reasons if there is a change of Type'

    If Target.Address = "$D$2" Then
    If Target.Validation.Type = "$F$2" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
    End If
    End If
    exitHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
    End Sub
```

What i'm looking to do is now extend this so it can work on a sheet where the dropdown lists will be in each cell of a column (ranged from M7:M500), and the indirect dropdown in each cell of (ranged from N7:N500)

So, when the user changes the original option in any of the cells in the M range, then the corresponding N cell in the same row will clear.

Does anyone know any examples i could potentially look at to make this work?

Comment: Whats the situation with the code posted, it doesn't work/doesn't do what you want?

Comment: The code i posted does work when there are two static cells holding the drop down lists each time they are used. I'm looking to add the drop down lists into each cell in the column ranges i mentioned. So, if there is a change to any of the original options in the M column the same clearing function can be called. Does that help clarify?

Comment: Just to close this question, i managed to find a solution by redesigning the worksheet to include a table and a combination of the maxcols and clear contents functions. Took awhile but got there.